# Python Not Running Code

Tags: python

I wrote a python script which just stopped working suddenly. I'm not sure why so any help would be appreciated. The console just doesn't display anything. I called the function start on the bottom but no luck.

```
import random

year = 1
our_score = 0
their_score = 0
games_played = 0

#opponent's strategy:
def op_strategy():
    for i in range (0,1):
        rand = random.randint(0,1)
    if rand == 0:
        return "war"
    if rand == 1:
        return "peace"


def start():
    global our_score, their_score, year
    print "====="
    print "Year " + str(year)
    print "Our Score: " + str(our_score)
    print "Their Score: " + str(their_score)
    print ""
    strategy = raw_input("What is your strategy this year? ")
    inputs(strategy)

def inputs(strategy):
    our_score = 0
    global our_score, their_score, year
    if str(strategy) == "peace" or str(strategy) == "war":
        print "You chose: " + str(strategy)
        op_strat = str(op_strategy())
        print "They chose: " + op_strat
    if str(strategy) == "war" and str(op_strat) == "war":
        print ">>> Everyoner to arms!"
        our_score = our_score + 1
        their_score = their_score + 1
        year = year + 1
    elif str(strategy) == "peace" and str(op_strat) == "peace":
        print ">>> Peace for everyone!"
        our_score = our_score + 3
        their_score = their_score + 3
        year = year + 1
    elif str(strategy) == "peace" and str(op_strat) == "war":
        print ">>> They crushed us!"
        our_score = our_score
        their_score = their_score + 5
        year = year + 1
    elif str(strategy) == "war" and str(op_strat) == "peace":
        print ">>> We crushed them!"
        our_score = our_score + 5
        their_score = their_score
        year = year + 1
    if str(year) == "11":
        print "====="
        print "Final"
        print str(our_score)
        print str(their_score)
        if our_score > their_score:
            print ">>>>> We win! <<<<<"
        if their_score > our_score:
            print ">>>>> They win! <<<<<"
        if their_score == our_score:
            print ">>>>> It's a tie! <<<<<"
        play = raw_input("Play again?")
        if play == "y":
            start()
        if play == "n":
            pass
        else:
            play = raw_input('Invalid response. Please enter "y" or "n".')
    if str(strategy) != "peace" and str(strategy) != "war":
        strategy = raw_input('Invalid strategy. Enter "peace" or "war": ')
        inputs(strategy)
    start()
start()
```

Comment: Python hates you.  What did you do to p!ss off that virtual machine?

Comment: Do you know how to use the python debugger? You could then answer this and similar questions by yourself.

Comment: What happens when you run the code?

Comment: @GregS I don't know how to use the python debugger... I'm a student learning it in class.

Comment: @Blender When I run the code the >>> shows up and nothing else.

Comment: Your `input` function calls `start`, and your `start` function calls `input`. This is a recipe for bad things, unless you know how to use recursion correctly. I can't say whether it's a problem now, but it probably will be later.

Comment: @senderle Good point but even if I remove it it still does not run. I also tried running other scripts which run fine so it's not python's fault.

Comment: well, it's (almost) never the fault of the programming language regardless of who it is that's doing the programming.

On topic: you should post what kind of output you are getting. As in copy/paste what happens when you do "python yourscript.py"

Comment: It works for me. How are you running it?

Comment: This is a good candidate for a class... btw you can change op_strategy() to use random.choice(("war", "peace")).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is executing, but it is stuck at the raw_input call, and not printing until it completes, which of course the user does not know to do because nothing has printed.
The buffer is not automatically flushed.  If you start python with the -u option, the buffer will be flushed with the raw_input call, and the prompt will be apparent.

Answer (score 1):

Load this up in **Idle** and you'll see the following error:

> SyntaxError: name 'our_score' is assigned to before global declaration (, line 1)

One these lines:

```
def inputs(strategy):
our_score = 0
global our_score, their_score, year
```

As detailed [here:](http://docs.python.org/reference/executionmodel.html#naming)

```
If the global statement occurs within a block, all uses of the name 
specified in the statement refer to the binding of that name in the top-level
namespace... i.e. the namespace of the module containing the code block
```

You've assigned to a local variable `our_name` and then you're telling the function to use a global variable of the same name. There should be no problems after fixing this.